# Awk/Sed: how to replace string?

Tags: shell, sed, awk

Given a data.json such as:

```
{ "key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3", "key4":"value4" },
{ "key1":"babla1", "key2":"babla2", "key3":"babla3", "key4":"babla4" },
{ "key1":"tata1", "key2":"tata2", "key3":"tata3", "key4":"tata4" },
```

how to replace the string `"key2":"(.*)", "key3":"(.*)"` by something else?

Comment: What did you try?  Why do you think it didn't work?

Comment: Begginer in shell, just forgot that ' "string" ' works. I currently only know deletion `sed -i 's/"key2".*"key4"//' data.json` but this will delete a part ("key4") of what I want to keep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$ sed 's|"key2":"[^"]*", "key3":"[^"]*"|"keyX":"test"|g' data.json
{ "key1":"value1", "keyX":"test", "key4":"value4" }, { "key1":"babla1", "keyX":"test", "key4":"babla4" }, { "key1":"tata1", "keyX":"test", "key4":"tata4" }
```

Some notes:

- because regexp is greedy I use `[^"]*` instead of `.*`
- `g` flag to replacing all occurences

Answer (score 0):

sed code:

```
sed 's/,.*,\s/, \"keyX\":\"testX\", /' file
```

..output is:

```
{ "key1":"value1", "keyX":"testX", "key4":"value4" },
{ "key1":"babla1", "keyX":"testX", "key4":"babla4" },
{ "key1":"tata1", "keyX":"testX", "key4":"tata4" },
```